# error while loading enumitem

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I have a big document and I'm trying to remove the indentation of itemize. I found that I could do this by using the `enumitem` package, but when I try to load it I get the following error:

```
document.tex:427: Undefined control sequence.
\enit@endenumerate ->\enit@after 
                                 \endlist \ifx \enit@series \relax \else \if...
l.427 \end{enumerate}
```

and in line 427 I defined an environment:

```
\begin{enumerate}[\it i)]
  \item item1
  \item item2
  \item item3
\end{enumerate}
```

I also tried to load the package at different locations. Does someone know what's happening?

**UPDATE**

I created a MWE where I only left the preamble:

```
\documentclass[oneside, a4paper, onecolumn, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} % use color
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=1.5cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx,hhline}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % labels beside the figure
\usepackage{quoting} % used for quote environment


\usepackage{floatrow} % for floatsetup
\usepackage{wrapfig} % for wrapping figures with text around
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{paralist} % inline list
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{scalerel} % for hybrida logo
\usepackage[natbib, backend=biber, sorting=none, doi=false, eprint=false, maxnames=99, firstinits=true, style=numeric-comp, url=false, isbn=false, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{setspace} % reduce space of bibliographic entries

% suppress In: in bibliographic entries
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shapes, decorations.shapes, shapes.symbols,calc,shadings,patterns,tikzmark,decorations.pathmorphing,fit,backgrounds}


\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{r-parens}{\slshape{(#2)}} %Define our custom label

% setup captions for figuress
\captionsetup{textfont=sl, justification=centering} % The general caption settings
\captionsetup[sub]{              % The subcaption settings
%    font=footnotesize,           % Make the font smaller for both label and text
    textfont=sl,                 % Make only the caption text slanted
    labelformat=r-parens}        % Use our custom label format



% add bibliography
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

% path for figures
\graphicspath{{./figures/}}

% hyperref setup
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6} % Link color
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
breaklinks=true,
urlcolor=linkcolour,linkcolor=linkcolour,
citecolor=NavyBlue} % Set link colors throughout the document

% hybrida logo
\def\hybrida{\scalerel*{\includegraphics{figures/hybrida}}{X\rule[-.6ex]{0pt}{1pt}}}

% remove space in the quoting environment
\quotingsetup{vskip=3pt}

% from texinfo.tex
\def\ifmonospace{\ifdim\fontdimen3\font=0pt }

% C++ text
\def\C++{%
\ifmonospace%
    C++%
\else%
    C\kern-.1667em\raise.50ex\hbox{\tiny{\textbf{+}\kern-.1em\textbf{+}}}%
\fi%
\spacefactor1000 } 



% remove indentation
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% change size of sections
\titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
%\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subparagraph}{\normalsize\bfseries}

% redefine section and subsection titles
%\titleformat{\section}
%  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.1pt]}]
%\titleformat{\subsection}
%  {\normalfont\fontsize{10}{10}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{10}{10}\bfseries\slshape}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.1pt]}]

\begin{document}

\newcounter{saveenum}

\begin{enumerate}[\itshape i)]
\item item 1;
\item item 2
\item item 3
\setcounter{saveenum}{\value{enumi}}
\end{enumerate}
And
\begin{enumerate}[\itshape i)]
\setcounter{enumi}{\value{saveenum}}
  \item item 4.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\it` is bad but that's not the cause. Try to load `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}` -- A MWE would be more helpful

Comment: Why is it bad? And what's the cause?

Comment: `\it` is old TeX syntax and is deprecated in `LaTeX`. Use `\itshape ...` rather. The cause is the special `counter` system used in `enumitem` -- your syntax is `enumerate` package style, which isn't supported by enumitem unless `shortlabels` option is used

Comment: Actually, I just removed the optional label entirely and it's still broken.

Comment: See my example below

Comment: That doesn't fix it. Any enumerate environment doesn't work.

Comment: Well, what shall we (or I) do now? You have shown a fragment of code only. What shall we guess out of that? ;-)

Comment: I'll try to come up with a MWE

Comment: That would be very nice!

Comment: I think, I spotted the cause: You're screwing up the counter values with your saveenum counter. You want to save values -- this can be done much more easily with start and resume

Comment: I commented the save counter lines, and still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I was too fast. I am digging into the code

Comment: `paralist` is the villain --> move the inclusion to a place before `enumitem`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit** (After update with MWE by the O.P.) The main cause is `paralist` which changes the settings of `enumerate` environment defined by `enumitem`.

If inline lists are required, use `\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}` and the `enumerate*` environment.

The `\begin{enumerate}[\it i)]` uses `enumerate` package syntax (apart from the 'wrong' `\it...` usage.)

This can only work together with `enumitem`, if the `shortlabels` package options is used.

Alternatively use `[label={\textit{\roman*)}}]` as label setting option to the environment or define a new list.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}[\itshape i)] % enumerate package style
  \item item1
  \item item2
  \item item3
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\textit{\roman*})}]  % enumitem style
  \item item1
  \item item2
  \item item3
\end{enumerate}
% Now resume it, i.e. continue it with iv, etc. 
\begin{enumerate}[label={\textit{\roman*})},resume]  % enumitem style
  \item item1
  \item item2
  \item item3
\end{enumerate}



\end{document}
```