# Ordered list causes error: Undefined control sequence, missing number for each sequence

Tags: lists, enumerate

I use the enumerate package and I thought this is a standard ordered list;

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Read the twitter dataset, divide the data into 3 groups. The training data is 85\% of the tweets, the validation is 10\% and the test is 5\%.
    \item Get the model and the optimiser for the selected transformer
    \item Check whether the setting in config.py requests uploading a model from a previous run. If it does, then load it, otherwise continue.
    \item 
\end{enumerate}
```

Yet I am getting error messages;

> Undefined control sequence, missing number for each sequence.

How do I fix this?

EDIT I have simplified the code to;

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item one
\end{enumerate}
```

And these are the error messages;
[image]
[image]

EDIT2 - after some more feedback I tried again;

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{report}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} % boldface caption title for floats
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item One.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I tried the various suggestions but I got the same error. I tried paralist, but that made no difference. I tried the solution in the suggested "duplicate question", but that didn't work.

Comment: the error message you show is not the format of a tex error message (which would show which command is undefined) show the exact error message from the log file (in a code block so line endings preserved) also we can not run your fragment to see the issue, please make teh example a small but complete document that gives the error.

Comment: I do not know where the log files are but I have updated my question and hopefully the details are more instructive.

Comment: You still haven't provided a *complete* small document, starting from `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, showing the packages that you load and all your settings. It *seems* that you have loaded the package `enumitem`, and it *may* be that you also use `paralist`, and it *may* be that you first load `enumitem` and then `paralist`. In this case (if you really need both packages), switching the order (loading first `paralist`, then `enumitem`) *might* solve the problem. However, since you don't give us any information, we cannot really give advice.

Comment: You have still provided no example, but the error message shows that the undefined command is `\enit@after` which is an internal command from the `enumitem` package. make sure you have loaded that package. (not `enumerate`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle wouldn't this error exactly indicate that the OP **is** using `enumitem`, otherwise we would not get `\enit@after` anywhere. But I agree, the OP need to provide a full but minimal example that generate this error

Comment: @daleif my guess is another package assuming enumitem is loaded and using its internals, but hard to guess with no example shown.

Comment: I assume that this is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278572/error-while-loading-enumitem since it shows the same error

Comment: Many thanks to @DavidCarlisle for suggesting I remove \usepackage{enumerate}. That fixed the problem.

Comment: it's always best to remove packages that I wrote

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You better send me a list, lol!

Comment: @arame3333 https://ctan.org/author/carlisle?lang=en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`enumerate` and `enumitem` are both redefining the `enumerate` environment, you can not load both, you need to decide which extension you want. But as `enumitem` does a lot more than `enumerate` (including an option to have a complete `enumerate` package emulation) the choice is quite simple: use the `enumitem` package and not `enumerate`.